# How to delete multiple item on php session?

Tags: php, session

Hi I have a shopping cart but my problem is when I delete multiple Item it wont process but if I delete only one item on check box it work well here is my code below I want to figure out if what is wrong on my code:

```
 $cart = $_SESSION['items'];

if(isset($_POST['del'])) {

  if ($cart) {
  $newcart = array();
  foreach ($cart as $item) {

    foreach ($_POST['itemid'] as $del) {
        $delete = $del;
    }

    if ($del != $item) {

          if ($newcart != '') {
            $newcart[] = $item;
          } else {
            $newcart[] = $item;
          }

    }   


  }
  $cart = $newcart; 
  }

}

$_SESSION['items'] = $cart;
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="itemid[]" value="1"></td><td>Item 1</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="itemid[]" value="2"></td><td>Item 2</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="itemid[]" value="3"></td><td>Item 3</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="itemid[]" value="4"></td><td>Item 4</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

If I check multiple Item and submit the delete button, the item was not delete but if I only check one the item deleted.

Thank you for you help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have name="items" in the code, but you're looking for $_POST['itemid'] - those should be the same as each other?  Looks like you're getting confused with the sessions value.

---

Post your edit:

```
foreach ($_POST['itemid'] as $del) { 
    $delete = $del; 
}
```

will leave only the LAST items as $delete. you could try

```
foreach ($cart as $item) { 

    if (!in_array($item, $_POST['itemid'])) { 

        if ($newcart != '') { 
            $newcart[] = $item; 
        } else { 
            $newcart[] = $item; 
        } 

    }    
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed it. Now I'ts okay, I have updated my question. Thank you.